# Coalesing with lags/leads over rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hey guys suppose I have a data frame

```
    Year   Month   1_month_sub   3_month_sub   12_month_sub
    2014     1         3             1              1
    2014     2         1             0              0
    2014     3         1             0              0
    2014     4         1             0              0
    2014     5         4             0              0
    2014     6         1             0              0
    2014     7         5             0              0
    2014     8         1             0              0
    2014     9         1             0              0
    2014     10        6             0              0
    2014     11        1             0              0
    2014     12        3             0              0
```

Where 1_month sub indicates that 1 month subscription was purchased, 3 month sub indicates that a 3 month subscription was purchased etc.
I need to add a column that gives me a # of monthly subscribers at any given unit of time. Thus the results would look like:

```
    Year   Month   1_month_sub   3_month_sub   12_month_sub  subs
    2014     1         3             1              1         5
    2014     2         1             0              0         3
    2014     3         1             0              0         3
    2014     4         1             0              0         2
    2014     5         4             0              0         5
    2014     6         1             0              0         2
    2014     7         5             0              0         6
    2014     8         1             0              0         2
    2014     9         1             0              0         2
    2014     10        6             0              0         7
    2014     11        1             0              0         2
    2014     12        3             0              0         4
    2015      1        1             0              0         1
```

I have used the COALESCE, LAG, LEAD functions with no real success. Any ideas on how I can approach this?

Comment: can you explain the calculation of subs column in the output?

Comment: Postgres doesn't really have a concept of "dataframe".  Is this information in a table?

Comment: Sorry - I am so used to R that I refer to everything as a data frame. Ya, I mean table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I speculate that the data is in a table and 1 month subs only exist for one month, 3 month for 3 months, and 12 months for 12 months.

And, further, I will assume that every month has a row.

You can do this in Postgres using a windowing clause on a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (1_month_sub +
        sum(3_month_sub) over (order by year rows between 2 preceding and current row) +
        sum(12_month_sub) over (order by year rows between 11 preceding and current row)
       ) as total_subs
from t;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I am a new big fan of the windowing clause - it has come in handy a few more times since then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

**EDIT:** @Gordon Linoff's answer below is better - same idea, but encapsulate the "previous 3" and "previous 12" values in single expressions!

```
select subs=(1_month_sub) + 
            lag(3_month_sub, 2, 0) over (order by Year, Month) +
            lag(3_month_sub, 1, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            3_month_sub + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 11, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 10, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 9, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 8, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 7, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 6, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 5, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 4, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 3, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 2, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            lag(12_month_sub, 1, 0) over (order by Year, Month) + 
            12_month_sub
from MyTable
```

Comment: You missed the lag-1 on the 12-month sub. ;)

Comment: I did something similar but I was using PARTITION and OVER together. I will give this a run in a little bit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thanks, your answer is the better one anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that without power features. Below has been tested on PostgreSQL and on MS SQL.

See on SQL Fiddle how it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/74862/4/0

Simple SQL Join

```
select
t1.Year,
t1.Month,
    sum(case when ((t2.Year-2014)*12+t2.Month) <= ((t1.Year-2014)*12+t1.Month) and ((t2.Year-2014)*12+t2.Month) - ((t1.Year-2014)*12+t1.Month) > -1 then 1 else 0 end * t2.one_ms) +
    sum( case when ((t2.Year-2014)*12+t2.Month) <= ((t1.Year-2014)*12+t1.Month) and ((t2.Year-2014)*12+t2.Month) - ((t1.Year-2014)*12+t1.Month) > -3 then 1 else 0 end * t2.three_ms ) +
    sum( case when ((t2.Year-2014)*12+t2.Month) <= ((t1.Year-2014)*12+t1.Month) and ((t2.Year-2014)*12+t2.Month) - ((t1.Year-2014)*12+t1.Month) > -12 then 1 else 0 end * t2.twelve_ms ) as subs
from Test t1
    join Test t2
        on 1=1
group by t1.Year, t1.Month, ((t1.Year-2014)*12+t1.Month)
order by ((t1.Year-2014)*12+t1.Month)
```

and the following characteristic function over Cartesian product:

```
  1 2 3 4 5
 +---------+
1|O . . . .|
2|O O . . .|
3|O O O . .|
4|. O O O .|
5|. . O O O|
 +---------+
```

work:

```
year    month   subs
2014        1       5
2014        2       3
2014        3       3
2014        4       2
2014        5       5
2014        6       2
2014        7       6
2014        8       2
2014        9       2
2014        10      7
2014        11      2
2014        12      4
2015        1       1
```

---

To understand it better you might want to give an alias to `(t1.Year-2014)*12+t1.Month` such as `num`:

```
alter table Test add column num int NULL

update Test
set num = (Year-2014)*12+Month

select
    t1.Year,
    t1.Month,
    sum(case when t2.num <= t1.num and t2.num - t1.num > -1 then 1 else 0 end * t2.one_ms) +
    sum( case when t2.num <= t1.num and t2.num - t1.num > -3 then 1 else 0 end * t2.three_ms ) +
    sum( case when t2.num <= t1.num and t2.num - t1.num > -12 then 1 else 0 end * t2.twelve_ms ) as subs
from Test t1
    join Test t2
        on 1=1
group by t1.Year, t1.Month, t1.num
order by t1.num
```